# Send BitMap object (and some other strings) via POST to a server

Tags: java, php, android

how would i go about sending a BitMap objects (and some other strings, such as name = "kevin") to a server? Does anyone have any examples on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you mean an image in bitmap format.

Just encode the bytes with Base64Encoder and pass it as just another POST parameter, and use Base64Decoder to get the original contents back.